# Android NDK DNS resolution with libresolv

Tags: android, c, dns, android-ndk, resolv

I want to use an existing C/C++ library in an Android project. The library contains calls to `res_query` in the `resolv.h` header (libresolv on Linux), which exists in the NDK and, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_(software)#Components), is part of Android's Bionic libc.

The program builds and links fine after removing the explicit link instruction `-lresolv` from the build file, but DNS resolution with `res_query` always fails (returns `-1`).

To further inspect this issue, I built an example program using only a single call to `res_query` using the example C++ project of Android Studio:

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/nameser.h>
#include <resolv.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_cpptest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    unsigned char buf[128];
    const int result = res_query("example.com", C_IN, T_A, buf, 128);
    if (result < 0) {
        herror(NULL);
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "CppTest", "DNS Error %d", h_errno);
        return env->NewStringUTF("DNS: Query failed.");
    }
    else
        return env->NewStringUTF("DNS: Query successful.");
}
```

This program, too, always fails with `result == -1` and `h_errno == 2`.

I have tried giving the app both `android.permission.INTERNET` and `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` without success.

Building this as a simple C command line application with the Android NDK CMake toolchain and pushing it onto the Android device with `adb`, it also exhibits the same behavior. Building the exact same code with a default Linux toolchain and executing it there works and returns a valid DNS response.

I cannot find any documentation or discussion online about the state of `resolv.h` on Android, except [this AOSP documentation page about DNS Resolvers](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/modular-system/dns-resolver#dns-q), which names `resolv` and states:

> The code in Bionic continues to exist for app compatibility reasons

suggesting that it should work in native app code.

I am aware that most Android systems do not ship with a `resolv.conf` file and this may very well be the issue. But bulletproof documentation stating this simply does not exist.
Does anyone know more specifically whether or not `resolv.h` **can** work in Android NDK apps to make DNS queries using the system-supplied DNS nameserver settings or not?

Comment: Also have issues when building mongo-c-driver under android platform.

Answer (score 0):

**res_query** is not supported in API level 29  and above.
You can replace  **res_query** by **android_res_nquery** and **android_res_nresult**

Check https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/networking for more details